# which one more preferable array_push() or array_merge() ,when one array is empty and another have some value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-merge, array-push

I am new to php ,facing some issues between array_push  and array_merge

> I used two array in input $a(Blank array) and $b(Associative array
>   with some value)

In case of array_merge

> when i used array_merge i got same result in both cases ($c and $f)
>   but in put i used an associative array with key "212" and value "aa"
>   but in output i get an array with key "0" and value "aa"

now in case of

> array_push i get 2 different outputs (int 1  and int 2)for two different
>   cases for 2 same inputs

I tried this

```
$a=array();
$b= array(212=>"aa");
$c=array_merge($a,$b);
$f=array_merge($b,$a);
$d=array_push($b,$a);
$e=array_push($a,$b);
```

now i dumped these array using this

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($c);
var_dump($f);
var_dump($d);
var_dump($e);
```

and i get these result for every array

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "aa"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "aa"
}
int(2)
int(1)
```

Comment: array_push modifies its first parameter and returns the number of new elements. so your experiment is somewhat flawed ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi what about in case of array_merge() .

Comment: look at answer 1 and/or read the manuals carefully, because I believe almost everything is answered already. sorry for the rtfm, but really.

Comment: array_push returns the new number of elements in the array.  `var_dump($b);` after your push to see what happened.  And likewise for $a after your second push.

Comment: array_merge merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array. ( From the manual.)  When looking in the manual, do check the explanation regarding the return of a function.